# How to hide `has_many` relationship ids from output of serializer?

Tags: active-model-serializers

I am using an `ActiveModelSerializer` to serialize a response for a public-facing API. The serializer has a `has_many` relationship in it, and as such is including a key in the output with the array of IDs from that relationship.

I'd like to not show ids to users of our API. Is there a way I can exclude this key from the serialized output?

Examples below; assume all `attributes` exist on the Model and in the database.

bike_serializer.rb:

```
class BikeSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  has_many :tires, serializer: TireSerializer

  attributes :category, :brand
end
```

tire_serializer.rb:

```
class TireSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  belongs_to :bike

  attributes :brand, :type, :diameter
end
```

Serialized output from, say, `bike_controller.rb`:

```
"bike": {
  ...
  "tire_ids": [1,2] # I want this excluded from the serialized output
}
```

Comment: i want to try this, can you share your working part of code in some ruby file

Comment: I'm not at my desk right now but I can send you instructions when I am!

Comment: Sure. Just drop in private message